# Executing delete command on MS-Access through VB.NET does not delete the records

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

Just trying to delete all rows of an Access table:

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click

    'Clear old records from extract table
    Dim sqlConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CLI_CRVM.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Dim intRC As Integer

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM [extract] ;"
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection

    sqlConnection.Open()
    intRC = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection.Close()
    MsgBox(intRC)
End Sub
```

I do not get any errors but it doesn't delete the rows either.  There are currently 10 rows in the table and the MsgBox shows 10 each time the button is clicked and there are still 10 rows in the table afterwards.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the asterisk:

```
DELETE FROM [extract];
```

You don't generally supply any columns in a `DELETE`. You only supply columns that you want to match a row against .. via a `WHERE` clause afterwards.

There are certain dialects of SQL that let you specify thresholds on what you delete in that part of the query - however, I don't believe Access' dialect does (I could be wrong).

Comment: Indeed MS Access supports `*` in the `DELETE` command. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177896(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @Caffé Apparently not in 2010 (as tagged by the OP). Interesting to note though. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @user3850146 Most strange part is the command returning 10 rows affected although the non supported syntax. I wouldn't be satisfied...

Comment: Even weirder, the documentation for the 2010 version remains the same (using `*` in the example). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195097(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: cc: @Caffé - There is something else at play here. I just tested `DELETE * FROM [extract] ;` against Access 2010 from VB.NET and it definitely did delete the rows.